Showing that the function that returns $1$ on the rationals and $0$ elsewhere has no limit at $0$. Is there anything wrong in this proof?
Define $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $f(x) = \begin{cases}1, & \text{if } x\in \mathbb Q \\ 0, & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb Q  \end{cases}$.
I want to show that this function has no limit at $0$ in $\mathbb R$.
The following is my attempt at showing this.
Proof: Suppose that $\lim_{x \to 0; x\in \mathbb R}f(x) = L$. Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that for all those values of $x\in \mathbb R$ for which $|x - 0| <\delta $, we have that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$. For $\varepsilon > 0$, clearly $|f(0) - L| = |1 - L| < \varepsilon$ as for every $\delta > 0$, we have that $|0 - 0| < \delta$. Let $0 < \varepsilon < |1 - L|$. Then by the above reasoning, we have that $|1 - L| < \varepsilon$. Which is a contradiction.
Is there any logical flaw in this proof?

It's very unclear what you say in the sentence that starts with "Because". No contradiction, but it would be clearer if you state that you are taking two sequences, both having the limit of zero, one of rationals, one of irrationals, and the limits are different.

The definition of limit only considers those $x\in\mathbb R$ satisfying $0 < \lvert x-0 \rvert < \delta$, and in particular it's inconclusive on how $\lvert f(0)-L\rvert$ compares with $\varepsilon$.

@Andrei I rewrote it more clearly.

@peterwhy There is no mention of the value less than $\delta$ being greater than $0$ in the book I am reading(Analysis 1 by Tao). It’s just the absolute value being less than $\delta$. I agree that with that restriction, the proof is wrong.

Then you have to disprove $L=1$, as then there would be no $\varepsilon$ satisfying $0<\varepsilon < \lvert 1-L\rvert =0$ to contradict $\lvert 1-L\rvert < \varepsilon$.

@peterwhy That makes sense. I felt there was something missing in the proof. Thank you!

As other comments suggested, I would say that you should consider the following reasoning for the proof of the first part of your post. It is rather classical and concise.
Let $u_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$ and $v_n=\frac{\sqrt2}{n+1}$ for all $n$. Then $(u_n)$ and $(v_n)$ tends to $0$ so if $f$ is continuous in $0$, $(f(u_n))$ and $(f(v_n))$ have the same limits. Contradiction, as for all $n$, $f(u_n)=1$ and $f(v_n)=0$.

Added a bit of annotations to the proposed proof attempting to point out some logical flaws.
Proof: Suppose that $\lim_{x \to 0; x\in \mathbb R}f(x) = L$.
Then for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta$ such that for all those values of $x\in \mathbb R$ for which $|x - 0| <\delta $, we have that $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.
<—— assuming $f(0)=L$ this is the definition of continuous at $x=0$ not of limit at $x=0$, the definition of limit requires $0<|x-0|<\delta$.
For $\varepsilon > 0$, clearly $|f(0) - L| = |1 - L| < \varepsilon$ as for every $\delta > 0$, we have that $|0 - 0| < \delta$. Let $0 < \varepsilon < |1 - L|$.
<—- this choice for $\varepsilon$ assumes $|1-L|\neq 0,$ that is $L\neq 1.$
Then by the above reasoning, we have that $|1 - L| < \varepsilon$. Which is a contradiction.
<——- the proof only considers the value of $f(x)$ at $x=0$, the point of limits and continuity at $x=0$ is to consider all values of $f(x)$ when $x$ is “close” to $x=0.$
